# Auto load data in Android listview when end of list is reached

Tags: android, android-listview

I need to implement custom listview that will fetch data from website. when the end of list is reached new api call is made. i wont mind if it keeps fetching new data in background and show it when list end is reached.

What is the best approach for it?

Right now i have created a scrollview. i make an api call fetch 10 records and create a linearlayout from it and add it to scrollview. i listen to scrolls and when its end is reached,  make a new api call and again add it to scrollview. But its performance is not good and also it freezes at times.

Any better approach to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually just wrote a blog about this last night.  It should do exactly what you are asking to do: http://www.thekeyconsultant.com/2013/02/android-simple-endless-lists-with.html . If you  need any clarification let me know.

That example starts loading the next data set when the view half way down the data set is loaded. In this way the user may never see the "end" of the list if they scroll slowly. You can change it so that it waits until the end if that is a requirement.

Comment: hey thanks for replying, i have not got chance to continue the thing, i will try it soon ans will let you know

Answer (score 0):

i suggest checking the scrolling instead of using the adapter, since you can handle any amount of items (even 0) and also customize when exactly to do extra loading, based on what the adapterView is telling what it sees .

here's a sample code:

```
mAdapterView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() 
  {
  ...
  @Override
  public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) 
    {
    final boolean needLoading =!mIsLoadingNewData&& firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= mAdapter.getCount() - 1;
    mIsLoadingNewData=true;
    if(needLoading)
      //load the new data and then update the adapter with new data and then set mIsLoadingNewData to false
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an implementation of the scroll listener which stores parameters in case you need to implement a paginated query, looking for different tens each time the scroll reaches the bottom.

```
    private class ScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

    private int currentScrollState;
    private int totalItemCount;
    private int currentVisibleItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private int pageSize = 10;
    private int offset = 0;

    public void setLoading(boolean loading) {
        this.loading = loading;
    }

    public int getPageSize() {
        return this.pageSize;
    }

    public int getOffset() {
        return this.offset;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
        this.isScrollCompleted();
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        this.currentVisibleItemCount = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount; // last item
        this.totalItemCount = totalItemCount;
    }

    private void isScrollCompleted() {
        if (this.currentVisibleItemCount > 0
                && this.totalItemCount - 1 == this.currentVisibleItemCount
                && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            // Detect if there's been a scroll which has completed and load more
            if (!loading && preguntas.getAdapter() != null) {
                loading = true;
                offset += pageSize;
                loadMoreData(offset, pageSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```